# How to adjust band heights (stretch and "shrink") so report occupies whole page?

Tags: jasper-reports

I’m new in Jasper Reports, so my problem may be easy for you, but is hard to me! I have a more complex report, but I create a new one, almost-empty, to exemplify it. In this example, I have two bands, the page header band and the details band. Inside the details band I put a frame, with a border all-around it.
My page header band can stretch, depending on the growth of data inside it. I need that page header first grows as it needs, AND THAN detail band grows FOR THE REST OF THE PAGE.

I tried to let detail band lower than the space for A4 paper, but it will stretch only if data inside of it requires, but I need that it grows ALLWAYS… So, I tried to pull it manually, during design-time, but than the header band could not grow, because there’s no space to do it (detail band does not “shrink” back if space is not used)…

Someone have any idea? Here is my code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="159b06a6-4453-4af1-aadf-8f0c096d21e9">
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
 <queryString>
  <![CDATA[]]>
 </queryString>
 <background>
  <band splitType="Stretch"/>
 </background>
 <pageHeader>
  <band height="168" splitType="Stretch"/>
 </pageHeader>
 <detail>
  <band height="188" splitType="Stretch">
   <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
   <frame>
    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="188" uuid="166cb97c-a43c-4a0d-8b73-692a1ccbc82f"/>
    <box>
     <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
   </frame>
  </band>
 </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: `I need that page header first grows as it needs, AND THAN detail band grows FOR THE REST OF THE PAGE.` - What if you have only one row to show? Your question is unclear. The image can help to understand your task/problem

Comment: I think you have an x-y problem, try to clarify what output you need

Comment: Hi @Alex! Hi @Petter! I'll try to clarify. Even if I have no rows to show, I need that detail band appears, showing that boxed frame, empty. The problem is that my page header band can grow (stretch), and if this happens, the detail band does not "shrink" to leave more page space to page header, even without rows to show...